# Construct non-binary tree from pre-order traversal

Tags: c++, tree

Given a list of nodes and the number of children it has, construct a (non-binary) tree from this list (which is in pre-order traversal)

for example I am given the following:

```
1 3
2 1
3 0
4 0
5 0
```

which is a tree that looks like

```
           1
          /|\
         / | \
        2  4  5
       /
      3
```

I know I should use recursion to construct this tree, but because it's not a binary tree, I'm pretty lost as to how this algorithm should be implemented.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Why don't you give it a try first. And when you get stuck, come back to the site and ask specific questions about your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before feeding you the code to solve your problem I'd like to play a thought game with you. Take a look at the following image which represents how recursions should unroll for your input

[image]

Study the image and notice how recursions are only started when there are children for a specific node (and that they last for the number of children indicated in the input).

Try to come up with a code (or a pseudocode) on paper.

---

The code to solve this it is pretty straightforward: use a `vector<Node>` to store your children

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
  Node(int v) : val(v) {}
  int val;
  vector<Node*> children;
};

Node *readTreeNode() {
  int val, children;
  cin >> val >> children;
  Node *node = new Node(val);
  for (int i = 0; i<children; ++i)
    node->children.push_back(readTreeNode());
  return node;
}

int main() {
  Node *root = readTreeNode();
  // Do the cleanup..
  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/Yc7Z4O)</kbd>

Notice the loop where the `readTreeNode()` function is recursively called

```
for (int i = 0; i<children; ++i)
    node->children.push_back(readTreeNode());
```

inner children are processed before the others.

Final caveats:

1. I didn't implement memory handling (the code above leaks memory). Be a good citizen and free your allocated memory or, even better, use smart pointers.
2. There's no error handling (i.e. no check for input nodes effectively being entered)